# Adding IE browser compatibility to HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

There is an application which works only in IE, not with any other browsers. I am using HtmlUnit to send the request by setting the mandatory field and clicking on the submit button, which is giving me Error Message -

> An internal error has occurred during processing

Though i have specified browserversion while creating the webClient object, like this

```
WebClient webClient = null;
BrowserVersion bv = BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11;
webClient = new WebClient(bv);
```

Can anybody please tell me what else am i missing here ?
Please let me know if there is any other way of getting this done here using HtmlUnit.